# Unexpected behaviour when passing a reference argument using a getter function

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm passing a reference argument using sfml getter function like:

ball.update(time, pad_player.getGlobalBounds(), pad_ia.getGlobalBounds(), score);

but appear this problem:

```
Pong.cpp: In member function ‘void Pong::run()’:
Pong.cpp:30:82: error: no matching function for call to ‘Ball::update(sf::Time&, sf::FloatRect, sf::FloatRect, Score&)’
   ball.update(time, pad_player.getGlobalBounds(), pad_ia.getGlobalBounds(), score);
                                                                                  ^
Pong.cpp:30:82: note: candidate is:
In file included from Pong.hpp:5:0,
                 from Pong.cpp:2:
Ball.hpp:10:7: note: void Ball::update(sf::Time&, sf::FloatRect&, sf::FloatRect&, Score&)
  void update(sf::Time& delta, sf::FloatRect& p1, sf::FloatRect& p2, Score& score);
       ^
Ball.hpp:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘sf::FloatRect {aka sf::Rect<float>}’ to ‘sf::FloatRect& {aka sf::Rect<float>&}
```

so if I change for this:

```
    sf::FloatRect player = pad_player.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::FloatRect ia = pad_ia.getGlobalBounds();
    ball.update(time, player, ia, score);
```

the program run correctly.

Why?

Comment: I think we need more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call with:

```
ball.update(time, 
            pad_player.getGlobalBounds(), 
            pad_ia.getGlobalBounds(), 
            score);
```

is interpreted as

```
Ball::update(sf::Time&, sf::FloatRect, sf::FloatRect, Score&)
```

There's a difference with your declaration:

```
void Ball::update(sf::Time&, sf::FloatRect&, sf::FloatRect&, Score&)
                                          ^               ^
//                                   expecting references here
```

Indeed, your second and third parameter are return values from function, which can only bind to lvalue parameters, const rvalue reference parameters to rvalue reference parameters (marked `&&`).

In this case, the easiest fix would be to change to const reference instead of just references, so that it works both for temporary AND for variables.

```
void Ball::update(sf::Time&, const sf::FloatRect&, const sf::FloatRect&, Score&);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that `Ball::update` is expecting nonconst `FloatRect` reference for parameters 2 and 3. Temporary return values cannot be bound to nonconst references in standard compliant compilers, so the error is quite correct.

If you have the option of changing `Ball::update` to take `const FloatRect&`, you should be able to do what you're attempting.